# Spring PagingAndSortingRepository delete entry during processing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Im using spring PagingAndSortingRepository to do pagination of database entries.
During processing i need to delete some entries..

when i call the repository to delete, the entry is deleted, after that the problem is with the next pageable. i'm not getting the size number of elements from the next Pageable (pageRequest.next();).

Is there any way to iterate with pagination and perform in parallel crud operation.

Part of the code

```
 while (!onePage.isEmpty()) {
                while (pageIterator.hasNext()) {
                    Object nextElement = pageIterator.next();
                    if (!falseCondition) {
                        log.info("sending message with Id {}", nextElement.getId());
                        repository.deleteById(nextElement.getId());

                    } else {
                        log.info("Lost connection");
                        return;
                    }
                }

                pageRequest = pageRequest.next();
                onePage = repository.findAll(pageRequest);
                pageIterator = onePage.iterator();

            }
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you not getting any results or are you not getting the correct results?

Comment: im not getting the correct result, getting one rundom entry from the db (size of the pagination is 3)

Comment: The page is built on the number of elements that the query returns and it's run every time you request next for the offset and page size. If you remove elements while processing the page the next page request will change. See the following example: 
Query complete results: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10.
First page (size 3): 1, 2, 3.
Remove 2.
Second page (size 3): 5, 6, 7.
As you can see the element 4 is not return because it has become part of the first page after removing 2. You can save the id of all the elements you want to remove and do it once the whole result set has been processed

Answer (score 2):

Like @ruba pointed out in the example, it is not a hibernate issue. Even if you using jdbc API directly you will have to handle the situation. I can propose you a solution

- You can implement your custom `spring-data-jpa` repository method where the service pass the `pageRequest` but you translate it to `offset` and `limit`. So instead of calling `pageRequest.next()` you do the following which takes into account of the items deleted.

```
        long nextPageNumber = pageRequest.getPageNumber() + 1;
        long nextOffset = nextPageNumber * pageRequest.getPageSize() 
                          - itemsDeletedInCurrentPage;
        long limit = pageRequest.getPageSize();
        
        List<Item> itemsInNextPage = em.createQuery(query)
                .setFirstResult(offset)
                .setMaxResults(limit)
                .getResultList();
```